# What happens when I instantiate a File in Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to understand how the `File` class works in Android. For instance, with the instruction:

```
File file = new File(MyActivity.this.getFilesDir().toString()+File.separator+"myfile.jpg");
```

Is the file created during the instanciation (with a 0 kb size) or when I write into it?

Comment: What happened when you googled? why were the results unsatisfactory? What is your guess at what is happening? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `File` object is actually a *path* to a file, not the actual file (despite the name). Think of them as glorified `String`s.

You can create `File` objects that point to nonexistent files, files in nonexistent directories, files with invalid paths, or files you don't have access to, without problems. In any of those cases, you will get an exception when you actually try to open the file (unless it simply doesn't exist and you're writing to it; that creates the file).

Answer (score 3):

Nothing happens on disk when you instantiate the file - you are just creating a file object that refers to a possibly-existent actual disk file.

If the disk file doesn't exist when you instantiate the File object, it won't exist until you create it using, for instance, createNewFile().